# What can I do to align svmono's gray box to be aligned properly?

Tags: pdftex, packages

I am using the document class **svmono.cls**, version v5.5 of 2009/12/17, to write a book. I am having problems getting the **svgraybox** environment to produce gray boxes whose edges are aligned to the edges of the external texts and whose text contents' edges are aligned symmetrically within the boxes.

The gray boxes in the sample texts given below illustrate my problem. Sample Text No. 1. is an extract from the **example.pdf** file provided by Springer. It shows the desired gray box. Sample Text No. 2. shows the gray box that I actually get. It differs significantly from what I should get.

[image: Sample Text 1]Sample Text No. 1.

[image]Sample Text No. 2.

The MWE code that produces the Sample Text No.2 is given below.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} 
\setcounter{section}{3}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}%
In order to avoid simply listing headings of different levels we recommend
to let every heading be followed by at least a short passage of text.
Use the \LaTeX automatism for all your cross-references and citations
citations as has already been described in Sect. 1.2.

Please note that the first line of text that follows a heading is not
indented, whereas the first lines of all subsequent paragraphs are.

\begin{svgraybox}
If you want to emphasize complete paragraphs of texts we recommend to use
the newly defined Springer class option \verb|graybox| and the newly
defined environment \verb|svgraybox|. This will produce a 15 percent
screened box 'behind' your text.

If you want to emphasize complete paragraphs of texts we recommend to use
the newly defined Springer class option and environment \verb|svgraybox|.
This will produce a 15 percent screened box 'behind' your text.
\end{svgraybox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The definition of the `svgraybox` in the class is wrong: it sets a right margin of 24pt and the result is exactly what you see.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{svgraybox}%
  {\begin{shaded}%
   \list{}{\leftmargin=\z@\rightmargin=\z@\topsep=\z@}%
   \expandafter\item\parindent=\svparindent
   \hskip-\listparindent}
  {\endlist\end{shaded}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} 
\setcounter{section}{3}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}
In order to avoid simply listing headings of different levels we recommend
to let every heading be followed by at least a short passage of text.
Use the \LaTeX automatism for all your cross-references and citations
citations as has already been described in Sect. 1.2.

Please note that the first line of text that follows a heading is not
indented, whereas the first lines of all subsequent paragraphs are.

\begin{svgraybox}
If you want to emphasize complete paragraphs of texts we recommend to use
the newly defined Springer class option \verb|graybox| and the newly
defined environment \verb|svgraybox|. This will produce a 15 percent
screened box 'behind' your text.

If you want to emphasize complete paragraphs of texts we recommend to use
the newly defined Springer class option and environment \verb|svgraybox|.
This will produce a 15 percent screened box 'behind' your text.
\end{svgraybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` in place of `mathptmx`. But use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much egreg. I tried out your modified form of the **svgraybox** environment. It worked very well for me. I made two modifications to your code: I replaced the environment **shaded** with the environment **shaded***; and `\z@` with `\p@`. My code appears below.

Comment: @user24098 `\p@` means `1pt`, while `\z@` means `0pt`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. My last comment was timed out. Here is may new code:
    \renewenvironment{svgraybox}%{\begin{shaded*}%
    \list{}{\leftmargin=\p@\rightmargin=\p@\topsep=\p@}%
    \expandafter\item\parindent=\svparindent
    \hskip-\listparindent}
    {\endlist\end{shaded*}}
I am also very grateful for your recommendation that I use **newtxtext** and **newtxmath** in place of **mathptmx**. This suggestion solves a big problem that I had with **mathptmx**.
Happy Easter!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the desired gray box using the code given below, thanks to the response by @egreg to the question I posted. My **svgraybox** environment is a slightly modified form of the one that was suggested by egreg.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{svgraybox}
  {\begin{shaded*}%
   \list{}{\leftmargin=\p@\rightmargin=\p@\topsep=\p@}%
   \expandafter\item\parindent=\svparindent
   \hskip-\listparindent}
  {\endlist\end{shaded*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} 
\setcounter{section}{3} 
\subsection{Subsection Heading}%
In order to avoid simply listing headings of different levels we recommend
to let every heading be followed by at least a short passage of text.
Use the \LaTeX\ automatism for all your cross-references and citations
citations as has already been described in Sect. 1.2.

Please note that the first line of text that follows a heading is not     
indented, whereas the first lines of all subsequent paragraphs are.

\begin{svgraybox}
If you want to emphasize complete paragraphs of texts we recommend to use
the newly defined Springer class option \verb|graybox| and the newly
defined environment \verb|svgraybox|.
This will produce a 15 percent screened box 'behind' your text.

If you want to emphasize complete paragraphs of texts we recommend to use
the newly defined Springer class option and environment \verb|svgraybox|.
This will produce a 15 percent screened box 'behind' your text.
\end{svgraybox}

\end{document}
```

The result is great!
[image]